# How to convert a list of forecasts into a normalized table in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am doing some time series forecasting in R using auto.arima() plus lapply to generate a number of forecasts for a bunch of stores like this:

my_data_set is a list of tibbles, each containing a store name, date (monthly) and a sales value

```
mod <- function(x) forecast(auto.arima(x$Value), h)
all_arima <- lapply(my_data_set, mod)
```

mod is a list of forecasts (one per store)

I'm struggling to get this into an more consumable output which would have a row per store/forecast period and columns for the upper/lower confidence intervals (80, 95) and a column for the mean prediction.

Would love suggestions on how to approach this differently if there is a better way to set it up from the start.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches you could use here: (1) use the forecast package as proposed; (2) use the fable package which is designed for this problem.

First, let's create some sample synthetic data.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
  Store = rep(c("A", "B"), c(200,200)),
  Month = rep(seq(as.Date("1995-01-01"), length=200, by="1 month"), 2),
  Value = rnorm(400)
)
```

For the forecast package, we will split the data into a list of tibbles. We can use the `as.data.frame()` function to make things easy in turning the forecast object into a data frame.

```r
# Using forecast package
library(forecast)
my_data_set <- split(df, df$Store)
mod <- function(x) {
  x$Value %>%
    ts(frequency=12, start=lubridate::year(x$Month[1])) %>%
    auto.arima() %>%
    forecast() %>%
    as.data.frame()
}
lapply(my_data_set, mod)
#> $A
#>          Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80  Lo 95 Hi 95
#> Sep 2011              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Oct 2011              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Nov 2011              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Dec 2011              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Jan 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Feb 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Mar 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Apr 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> May 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Jun 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Jul 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Aug 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Sep 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Oct 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Nov 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Dec 2012              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Jan 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Feb 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Mar 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Apr 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> May 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Jun 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Jul 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> Aug 2013              0 -1.327999 1.327999 -2.031 2.031
#> 
#> $B
#>          Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
#> Sep 2011              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Oct 2011              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Nov 2011              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Dec 2011              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Jan 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Feb 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Mar 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Apr 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> May 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Jun 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Jul 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Aug 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Sep 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Oct 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Nov 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Dec 2012              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Jan 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Feb 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Mar 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Apr 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> May 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Jun 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Jul 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
#> Aug 2013              0 -1.274651 1.274651 -1.949411 1.949411
```

To use the fable package, we can just take the original data frame with all stores included, and turn it into a tsibble object, then pipe it to model and forecast as follows.

```r
# Using fable
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
df %>%
  mutate(Month = yearmonth(Month)) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=Month, key=Store) %>%
  model(ARIMA(Value)) %>%
  forecast() %>%
  mutate(
    pi80 = hilo(Value, 80),
    pi95 = hilo(Value, 95)
  ) %>%
  unpack_hilo(cols = c(pi80, pi95))
#> # A fable: 48 x 9 [1M]
#> # Key:     Store, .model [2]
#>    Store .model          Month     Value .mean pi80_lower pi80_upper pi95_lower
#>    <chr> <chr>           <mth>    <dist> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 A     ARIMA(Value) 2011 Sep N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  2 A     ARIMA(Value) 2011 Oct N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  3 A     ARIMA(Value) 2011 Nov N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  4 A     ARIMA(Value) 2011 Dec N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  5 A     ARIMA(Value) 2012 Jan N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  6 A     ARIMA(Value) 2012 Feb N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  7 A     ARIMA(Value) 2012 Mar N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  8 A     ARIMA(Value) 2012 Apr N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#>  9 A     ARIMA(Value) 2012 May N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#> 10 A     ARIMA(Value) 2012 Jun N(0, 1.1)     0      -1.33       1.33      -2.03
#> # … with 38 more rows, and 1 more variable: pi95_upper <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This approach is also much more flexible as there may be multiple grouping variables (Stores and Products, for example).  The fable approach is documented in the open access textbook at https://OTexts.com/fpp3.

Comment: thanks Rob - this is fantastic!  I was not familiar with these other packages.  Quick question - does this implementation model(ARIMA(Value)) allow me to specify the number of forecast periods?

Comment: The number of forecast periods is specified in the forecast function, not the model function.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `forecast` is a `list`.  We can extract the components and convert to `data.frame`

```
library(forecast)
mod <- function(x) {
       frcst <- forecast(auto.arima(x$Value), h)
       data.frame(Mean = as.numeric(frcst$mean), 
                  lower = as.numeric(frcst$lower[, "95%"]),
                  upper = as.numeric(frcst$upper[, "95%]))
   }
```

and then apply the function

```
lapply(my_data_set, mod)
```